# C++11 constructor argument: std::move and value or std::forward and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, copy-elision

Which of the below two should be preferred and why?

```
struct X {
    Y data_;
    explicit X(Y&& data): data_(std::forward<Y>(data)) {}
};
```

vs

```
struct X {
    Y data_;
    explicit X(Y data): data_(std::move(data)) {}
};
```

Comment: POD's do not have user defined constructors! I'd prefer the second one because the first will not bind to lvalues. Also, the first one should be `std::forward<Y>(data)`.

Comment: Please replace `std::forward` with `std::move` in the first one. `std::forward` only makes sense in combination with template parameters.

Comment: Added template parameter to `forward`

Comment: @Praetorian As far as I know, a POD can have user-defined constructors (!= aggregate). There can, however, be no user-defined default, copy or move constructors (or dtors).

Comment: @dyp I was under the impression a POD is an aggregate whose members are also PODs, i.e the requirements are stricter than those for aggregates. Can't check at the moment ...

Comment: @Praetorian Sounds reasonable, but I think a POD is simply a requirement for a certain layout, not for a certain usage. [class]/10 just says "A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no
non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types)."

Comment: I updated the question to keep the discussion close to the point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two variants differ in functionality. The following statements work for the second one–but not for the first one:

```
Y y;
X x(y);
```

If you are looking for the same functionality, the two variants should look as follows:

```
struct X
{
    Y data_;
    explicit X(const Y& data) : data_(data) { }
    explicit X(Y&& data) : data_(std::move(data)) { }
};

struct X
{
    Y data_;
    explicit X(Y data) : data_(std::move(data)) { }
};
```

The first variant saves one *move* operation, whereas the second variant is less to write. So, the answer is: Use the latter as long as you have no reason to optimize the performance.

Comment: Shouldnt this read "The first variant saves one *copy* operation"? (Namely, when we have an rvalue and can use the move constructor, where the second variant would still have to copy its argument)

Comment: If we have an _rvalue_, then the parameter _data_ in the second variant will be constructed with the _move constructor_, i.e. the object will moved twice, first from the argument into the parameter, and then from the parameter into the member variable. There is no additional _copy operation_ compared to the first variant. There is only an additional _move operation_.

Comment: @nosid Doesn't it depend on usage, whether the single move will be saved? Please see [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332333/c11-constructor-argument-stdmove-and-value-or-stdforward-and-rvalue-refer/78191839#answer-78191839).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first variant only "sometimes" saves on move operation.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    S() = default;
    S(const S& other) { std::cout << "copy" << std::endl; }
    S(S&& other) { std::cout << "move" << std::endl; }
};

struct Owner
{
    Owner(S s) : s(std::move(s)) {}
    //Owner(S&& s) : s(std::move(s)) {} // this will "sometimes" save a single move
    S s;
};

S createS()
{
    return S();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "owner1:" << std::endl;
    Owner owner1 = Owner(S());

    std::cout << "owner2:" << std::endl;
    Owner owner2 = Owner(createS());

    std::cout << "owner3:" << std::endl;
    S s;
    Owner owner3 = Owner(std::move(s));

    return 0;
}
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABwArKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIGYapAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BfkG19dlNLQRl0XEJSSkKza3t%2BV3j/YMVVaMAlLaoXsTI7BwmGgCC5gDMEcjeWADUJgdu4/iCAHQIl9g7%2B2ZHDCde55duTuPEmFYTxeh2Op0wFyuCn%2BgJYwL2oI%2B4MhbgIAE9UpgAPoEYhMQgKeGvd6fb5XNgsEhoomI0kQn4AN0wDhINLeYK%2B9KuDJaeEMBBpe3%2BXgcZyEIIA7FY9mdZWKIEtIQARM5YKhMLy0AUHaW7OXytAMcZi8wANjOqAICASipMUrONxAKDWBBRPwuZjMaFS1M9bquDoI6CdrlolwsFwlSpe%2BqEEHFZlNZotVptkYjjudXldP3d5jMlKZ%2Bf9bkDwZAofDkejCKj4ZBQtxItdAHkAO6RYiS3X69ud%2BMOxUgB0QTOFzCjpa2qV2mt6uUAegXZz7CXjZuTCiHI7HqCZk%2BnVijZyXZyteAUZzbdFoHrMClQbEcbEJfoUTCZZyYDoiwHoZ3HGM5SEB161raMdQbXYQOQAEmAITA4yWbsgNlAECHWBh5WQyDwKgiJXRYfEGAVFCZTlTM0GzEs71QDsEi4EBi1zANM0rXD51lVdiAtejiC4ZUVz4%2BMFRw3VULLJ0qJzK4809OjOzMJi/RY0s2IYdAww43s%2BN4xTBO4iBYMBBCkLEqD9Uol0aPzBSEgOZSzBo9TNLAzixVA7S5W4vT7IM4Td33LdzIRci0MwDDiCwjQ3NnF4OBWWhOECXg/A4LRSFQTg3GsawHTWDZ6TeHhSAITQEpWABrEBTQ0O4uAATkkLgJUkCVAglMx/C4QJgiSjhJFS8rMs4XgFBAFIyvShLSDgWAYEQZ0WFSOgEnISg0GW1bEhOQxgBajQuD4OgEOIcaIFiYbYgiFo0U4ErruYYg0RbWJtGZKaSs2thBBbBhaDu6bSCwWIvGANwxFocbuF4LAiKMcQgfwAEHDwJloYyzBVGZbMtgygi6mG2g8FiPFno8LBhtxPAWHumaqAMYAFAANTwTA2xbTE0pK/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1CB3QjoMIwUFyyx9BJ8bIBWVBUgaaGAFobkuJVTEsawWt4PcEmIPAsCVhVug%2B7IXA0qY/COsIIiGSoRiOoosgEe29A9hp5mGRIjrsa2BD6SZPA6PRg9R0OJgGZ2Fjd2w4%2B9oO4/913A5WB91k2CREuSoagayjgzlUfxTQ101JDOXajDOFq7jqgSIFwQgSA9A4uCWXgpq0KdSGqyQ6reBqWrMQIGrMLguAOCVTX0ThBtIWnkjuVqGtNU1AgOMwJQaiUgn8Ug0oykuxom0rypWObFpdVJs3WozHxW%2BhiCiVgtnLyvq9r6XgAbhKJu9VeCYHwEQU2wYjq82EKIcQQsYGizUMNSWpA2x4lSHTAuHAUon2GiXFs2YH6ulQFQMuFcq41zrgAxuzczgQA8FtN%2Bndu692visa0TAsCJEtv1ZetN953AnhoA4BxJCmk6hoaezU8HF1GrYS%2BfcKqDxAAcBqdx/AaECP4CeZhJB7y4P4SQfVOAHCLmfeRSiB79TMOYo2lj2GkCZGdG2kggA)

Only use-case `owner3` seems to have the two moves. However I agree that second variant is probably better until you measure that it's really a performance issue in your particular application.